# Ignore something from iTunes home sharing

Tags: itunes

Can I ignore something from home sharing? Mainly podcasts. I don't care about that stuff, so I want it to not even show up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "Sharing" section of iTunes' preferences window, you can configure things there to only share specific sections of your iTunes library over the network, rather than the entire library.

Comment: question is phrased to suggest the opposite problem -- that others have shared entire libraries, and he wants to pick and choose what is displayed/used by his system.  just pointing out that this answer configures the **server**, not the **client**, and that i interpret the question as about client configuration.  my interpretation could well be incorrect.